# Approximate cloning of a quantum state, informed by past measurements

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, approximations, algorithms

Suppose I give you a state $|\psi\rangle$, and tell you a sequence of measurements that have been performed on it. The measurements are not guaranteed to be orthogonal to each other, or to cover the entire state-space.

Your goal is to produce an approximate clone of $|\psi\rangle$. Something that will be difficult to distinguish from the original $|\psi\rangle$. The measurement results provide valuable information for beating the fidelity of the [optimal uninformed cloning method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9804001v1.pdf).

How easy is this to do, supposing we have access to a quantum computer?

---

**Example Problem**

1. $|\psi_0\rangle$ was drawn uniformly at random from the space of 2-qubit (i.e. 4-level) pure states.
2. $|\psi_0\rangle$ was measured along the first qubit's diagonal X+Z axis and the result was -1. The measurement perturbed $|\psi_0\rangle$, giving $|\psi_1\rangle$.
3. $|\psi_1\rangle$ was measured along $Z \otimes Z$ and the result was +1, producing $|\psi_2\rangle$.
4. We want to approximately clone $|\psi_2\rangle$.

---

**Naive Classical Solution**

Classically, we could simulate hitting a maximally-mixed density matrix $\rho$ with a post-selection for each measurement (in order). We then produce the described $\rho$ with a quantum computer. Finally, when performing [the optimal uninformed cloning method](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9804001v1.pdf) on a quantum computer, we concatenate $\rho$ onto $|\psi\rangle$ before projecting onto their symmetric subspace (normally we'd have used a maximally-mixed state instead of $\rho$).

The problem with this solution is that we have to operate on a huge density matrix classically. For an $n$-qubit system and a list of $m$ measurements, it takes $O(m 4^n)$ time.

---

**Naive Quantum Solution**

We can avoid the $4^n$ cost of the classical solution by performing the measurements and post-selections with a quantum computer initialized with a random state. However, since we don't live a Post-BQP universe, the post-selection procedure is actually just measuring, hoping the answer comes out right, and starting over if it didn't.

Optimistically assuming each measurement is 50/50, we get a lower bound of $\Omega(2^m)$ on the worst-case time.

(If the measurements were guaranteed to be orthogonal, and had to be described in terms of a quantum circuit to perform the necessary basis transformation, we could just use them as a description of how to initialize a subset of $|\psi\rangle$ and be done in polynomial time. The overlap is what causes so much trouble.)

---

**How efficiently can optimal measurement-informed approximate cloning be performed?** Is there a solution that's polynomially expensive in terms of both the number of qubits and the number of measurements?

Comment: Still trying to get around the no-cloning theorem? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne More like exploring the boundaries around it. Violate some of the assumptions, see how the conclusion varies.

Comment: If you are willing to violate the laws of nature, then everything is possible. Take for instance the third law of thermodynamics... get yourself a negative temperature bath... voila... instant perpetual motion machine! :-)

Comment: What are you violating? Sounds like a perfectly reasonable protocol (if I interpret it correctly -- but admittedly I find it hard to follow what you are actually asking: It might help if you would be more concise).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch In this case the precondition being violated is "no information about the state". It won't always allow ideal cloning, but the approximation will get better. I was very un-concise and explicit because of how much flak I got from CuriousOne when I asked a similar question yesterday.

Comment: And which law of nature is thereby violated?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Oh, you were talking to CuriousOne. None of the laws of nature are violated by the question's problem statement. I was referring to "unknown state" precondition of the no-cloning theorem in my comment about violating (or weakening in this case) assumptions.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I already mentioned the law that is violated by any such scheme (it is even violated by the assumptions of the no-cloning theorem, already). The temperature of the measurement device can not be 0K, i.e. there is always classical noise on top of every quantum mechanical measurement. If the OP actually cared about understanding something about nature, he would focus his attention on the consequences of that, which, in terms of pure quantum mechanics, means that he needs to understand how even multiple weak measurements are introducing uncertainty into the original state.

Comment: @CuriousOne Wouldn't understanding the setup at 0K be a first step towards understanding it at finite temperature?  (And there are scenarios where the temperature is sufficiently close to 0K).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I agree that the OP doesn't even understand it at 0K. Personally I have very low hopes that he is actually trying to understand it. My first comment stands, he is trying to make a run around the no-cloning theorem (as trivial as it is) and that's pretty much that.